# Writting Folder causes error code 80

Tags: installation, nsis

My NSIS installer is giving a error code of 80 when I attempt to copy/overwrite a folder. I think it may have to do with the fact that the folder I am attempting to copy to the users HD already exists. But in my case I will always want to overwrite it.

What does the error code 80 mean?

Heres my code:

```
# Write plugins to EXDS_Customisation\EXDS_USER\
ClearErrors
SetOverwrite try
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\EXDS_User\"
FILE /r "${localInstallDir}\EXDS_Customisation\EXDS_User\${MAINPLUGINSDIR}"

${If} ${Errors}
    System::Call "Kernel32::GetLastError() i() .r1"
    # Prints: "Error code: 80"
    MessageBox MB_ICONINFORMATION|MB_OK "Error code: $1 "
        Quit
${EndIf}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always want to overwrite, why are you using `Try` and not `SetOverwrite On`?

Using `System::Call "Kernel32::GetLastError()...` is **never** valid. System::Call has a special `?e` option but it is not useful in your case. You cannot get specific error information from NSIS, all you have is just the error flag...